# Why are class definitions automatically recognized without importing them

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a `main.ts`

```
window.onload = function() {

    let test: Testing = new Testing();

};
```

and a `Testing.ts`

```
class Testing {

}
```

and here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false
}
```

So I'm wondering why without importing the `Testing` class in `main.ts`, typescript is able to find it automatically.

And then weirdly enough, when I change the `Testing` class to include an `export` before it, typescript all a sudden complains saying, `Cannot find name 'Testing'`. And only when I import the `Testing` class in my `main.ts`, then will it start working.

I'm assuming this question is regarding to how modules work, so if someone could explain what's going on here, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Visual Studio Code

Comment: If your bundler puts it all in one file wouldn't need imports

Comment: Probably the file counts as a script (which runs in global scope) until you add an `export` or `import` statement which marks it as a module with its own local scope.